# How to split the string by certain amount of characters in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

How to split the string by certain amount of characters in Ruby?

For example, suppose that I have the following string:

> some_string

and I want to split it by every 4th character, so the resulting strings will look like this:

```
som
e_s
tri
ng
```

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you split [in front of] every fourth character, you should get `som, e_st, ring`.

Comment: If you split by every fourth character, you should get `som, _st, ing`.

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: @sawa It is very clear, considering he gave an example which shows the desired output. It might not be worded exactly right, but it is not unclear given the full context of the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```
'some_string'.chars.each_slice(3).map(&:join)
# => ["som", "e_s", "tri", "ng"]
```

Using regular expression:

```
'some_string'.scan(/.{1,3}/)
# => ["som", "e_s", "tri", "ng"]
```